# Is sliding mode control complete in mathematics?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory, continuity

Consider a double integrator control system

$$\begin{cases}\dot{x}_1 = x_2,\\\dot{x}_2=u,\end{cases}$$

where $\dot{x} := \mathrm{d}x/\mathrm{d}t$. Then we apply the sliding mode control $u = -\beta(x)\mathrm{sgn}(s)$ with $s = a x_1+x_2$ ($a > 0$), in which $\beta(x) \geq a x_2 + \beta_0$ ($\beta_0 > 0$), and

$$\mathrm{sgn}(s)=\begin{cases}1, & s > 0,\\ 0, & s = 0,\\-1,& s<0.\end{cases}$$

By setting the Lyapunov function as $V = s^2/2$, any trajectory initially with $s \neq 0$ will reach $s = 0$ in finite time. This is because

$\dot{V} = s \dot{s} = s(a \dot{x}_1 + \dot{x}_2) = sa x_2 + su \leq |s|ax_2 + s [-\beta(x)\mathrm{sgn}(s)] = |s|(ax_2 - \beta(x)) \leq -\beta_0|s|.$

The above inequality also implies that: when reaching the manifold $s = 0$, the trajectory cannot leave it. On the manifold $s=0$, state $x_1$ follows $0 = s = ax_1 + x_2$, i.e., $\dot{x}_1 = -a x_1$, which means $(x_1, x_2)$ will finally converge to $(0,0)$ (along $s = 0$, since the trajectory cannot leave $s = 0$) as time goes to infinity.

However, here is the interesting thing. Do you really think $(x_1,x_2)$ will move along $s = 0$? Let's check the vector field at $(x_1, x_2)$, and it will gives

$$\begin{cases}\dot{x}_1 = x_2,\\\dot{x}_2=u=-\beta(x)\mathrm{sgn}(s)=0,\end{cases}$$

which never points along $s = ax_1 + x_2$ (recall that $a > 0$), and it will leave $s = 0$ instantly. This result contradicts "when reaching the manifold $s = 0$, the trajectory cannot leave it" implied by the Lyapunov function. What's happened on $s = 0$?

Comment: The conventional solutions cease to exist at $s=0$, at least for $x_2>0$, as these are only defined for domains with continuous vector fields. What generalized solution definition are you using to extend these conventional solutions?

Comment: @LutzL Thanks very much! Yes, the vector fields are not continuous (PS: Can we say that the vector fields do not exist on the manifold $s = 0$?). For the generalized solution of an ODE, so sorry I am not familiar wtih its definition. What kind of generalized solution can describe the actual trajectory of the system? Thanks a lot!

Comment: One way is to approximate the right side, like with $sgn(x)\approx 2\frac{x}{\epsilon+|x|}$ and the same shifted a little to the side. Then look if anything is common quantivatively or only qualitatively among the solutions to these approximations. This essentially is the distributional approach of Fillipov(?).

Comment: @LutzL Thanks so much for your answer. I think I need to read some textbooks and get some background on the generalized solutions in Filippov sense.

Answer (score 0):

I read your post many times.
I am not an expert in sliding mode control but I did learn a little bit about it.
Sliding mode control brings your system(dynamics of the system expressed with a system of differential equations) to a sliding surface where some desirable properties are sought-after. Once the attraction to sliding surface is realized, the first system is turn into another system whose dynamics lie exclusively on the sliding surface.

In the case above, the system initially (outside the sliding surface) is expressed as :

dx1 = x2
dx2 = u

but once the system is brought to the sliding surface s = ax1+x2 = 0, it is confined  there (assuming you have proved it , of course), Finally the dynamics of your system are described by the equation :

dx1 = -ax1

which means the original dynamics of the system do not describe the system motion no longer, but are turned to another dynamics specified by the sliding surface choice..

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer, oussama. [+1] This system is quite different from an ordinary one (whose solution is continuously differentiable), since the solution is in Filippov sense. When the system state is on the surface $s = a x_1 + x_2$, the control input will be $u = 0$. This means $x$ will be away from $s$. Thanks again for your answer :-)